# Fullcalendar V4 - hide next and previous option based on condition?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using **Version-4 Fullcalendar** in my Ruby on Rails application. My fullcalendar view is set to **week** and there is a button of next week and previous week which render the data based on start date and end date. Now I have to hide next and previous option on condition :-

- hide next button if (end_date > date.today + 30 days) else show
- hide previous button if (start_date < date.today - 30 days) else show

I tried using code :-

```
eventRender: function (info) { 
        // render code
      },
```

but its executed on every event and also I am not able to get start and end date of calender in eventRender.

Can anyone suggest me to use any-other callback which is called only once after or before render of all events and also how can I get start and end date of calender in that callback.

Comment: You don't need to show and hide the buttons necessarily. Just use the validRange option to restrict the date range that the user is allowed to navigate to. The buttons won't hide, but they will stop working when the user tries to move outside the range specified

Comment: I need only callback which execute after/before rendering of events, and there I can write show-hide js code.

Comment: Use of the next/prev buttons is unrelated to the rendering of events. Did you try the validRange as I suggested?

Comment: I tried but still buttons are clickable.

Comment: You'd better show us what you tried then, then we can check it for you, and help you to get it right. Please update your post.